# How to animate UIBezierPath's endAngle in UIKit like SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, uikit

I need to create smooth endAngle animation in UIKit like animatableData + endAngle in SwiftUI

I've made some kind of pie timer, I need to animate it collapse.
I created it using UIBezierPath, but with CABasicAnimation or UIViewAnimate I can't animate it's endAngle.
But I did it with SwiftUI using animatableData inside Shape and linear animation.
[SwiftUI animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZMSJ.gif)
Is there any options to make it work with UIKit?

This is the code I use to draw a pie:

```swift
    private func getInnerTimerPiePathByPercent() -> CGPath {
        let radius: CGFloat = (min(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) - 34) / 2
        let filledPercent: CGFloat = 1 - clearSegmentPercent
        let start: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 2 * 3
        let end = getEndAngleByPercent(filledPercent)
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2,y:bounds.size.height / 2)
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: center)
        bezierPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: start, endAngle: end, clockwise: false)
        bezierPath.addLine(to: center)
        return bezierPath.cgPath
    }

    private func getEndAngleByPercent(_ percent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        -CGFloat.pi * 2 * percent + CGFloat.pi / 2 * 3
    }
```

This is the code I used in animation:

```swift
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.duration = 10
        animation.toValue = getInnerTimerPiePathByPercent(percent: 0)
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        innerTimerPieShapeLayer?.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: There are various ways to animate a "pie wedge" ... take a look at this answer and see if it fits your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954485/6257435

Comment: @DonMag this is what I looked for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`UIBezierPath` is not a UI element on its own. You use it to configure something like a `CAShapeLayer`. You can see [in the docs for CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer) that many of its properties are animatable. In your case, it seems like you want to animate the `path` property using a `CABasicAnimation`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thanks.
With path I can't animate it too

Comment: Let me know if the `path` animation works for you.

Comment: @EVGKZN will you post the `CABasicAnimation` code that you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: I used something like that
`let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.duration = 10
animation.toValue = getInnerTimerPiePathByPercent(percent: 0)
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
innerTimerPieShapeLayer?.add(animation, forKey: nil)`

And got this 
[link](https://imgur.com/a/JUuV4sS)

Comment: I added code examples to question @dalton_c